# HMAC Licensing Example Does Not Make Sense

Tags: c#, byte, licensing, hmac, bit

I am researching licensing solutions for a project of mine, one article has the following text:

"The expiration date is represented as days (not seconds) since 1/1/1970. This way it only takes two bytes to represent the date" - [http://www.drdobbs.com/licensing-using-symmetric-and-asymmetric/184401687?pgno=1][1] (under the heading "HMAC Licensing System" about half way down)

How can this be correct if the days returned are a 32-bit integer, how can this guy fit that info into 2 bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply truncate a 32 bit integer to 16 bits. An unsigned 16 bit integer has a maximum of 65535, which, if expressing a number of days, is over 179 years.